# Regular Expression for string with exception

Tags: regex, vba

I want to check if a string contains 4 letters/numbers inside parentheses. ex : (A1B2), (1111), (BBBB) but not a certain code (WXYZ).

I know that | is the "OR" operator and I could find a "AND" operator.

I have 2 conditions.

So far I have the regex for the first one :

```
[(]\w{4}[)]
```

I don't know how to verify that this is respected + my second condition of not being (WXYZ).

I need something that looks like:

```
[(]\w{4}[)] AND not (WXYZ)
```

I tried multiple times using  ^ operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
\((?!WXYZ)\w{4}\)
```

The `(?!WXYZ)` basically means that the next characters can't be this, but it doesn't move the position forward.

The `\(` is an escaped parenthesis - it is similar to your `[(]` in that it will treat the `(` as just a character, not as a special meta-character... but the slash is the usual way to do it.

The `?` in both this and the other answer is actually part of an instruction (it follows a bracket): in my case `?!` the negative lookahead for the group... in @herbae's one it is a positive lookahead (`?=`). "Normally" the `?` would just mean optional...

Good luck. Keep at it - regexp is one of the most powerful tools you can learn! (and a great resource is [Regular-Expressions.info Turorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html))

Comment: Alright thanks it's perfect. Using ? is really good to verify 2 conditions since it doesn't move the position. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: note that it is `(?!   )` that is the important bit - not just the `?`! - sorry that my original explanation (but not the regexp itself) had a typo!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\(((?=[^WXYZ])\w{4})\)
```

The "\" is an escape character for both parenthesis.
The "?=" is a positive lookahead. I'm saying "after the first parenthesis, do not find any WXYZ sequences".

Comment: it needs to allow the letters, just not this specific order.
with your regex (WWWW), (ZYWX), etc doesn't work but it has to work, just not (WXYZ) in that order. Can you explain me the backslash and ? mark . thank you

Comment: You are actually saying to find a single character that is not one of WXYZ at the start of your group of 4, rather than the WXYZ sequence... For example, `(XABC)` will fail this test because it starts with one of those 4